# Yii2 GridView Filtering on Relational Column not Responding

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to filter on a relational data column.

In my search model, I added the field

```
public function attributes()
{        
    // add related fields to searchable attributes
    return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['customerProductBaseProduct.product_name');
}
```

Made it a safe search field

```
['customerProductBaseProduct.product_name'], 'safe'],
```

To the model's search function, I added a $query->joinWith

```
$query = CustomerProducts::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here
    $query->joinWith(['customerProductBaseProduct']);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);
```

And a ->andFilterWhere

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_product_customerID', $this->customer_product_customerID])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_product_formula', $this->customer_product_formula])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_product_name', $this->customer_product_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_product_sub_name', $this->customer_product_sub_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_product_spanish', $this->customer_product_spanish])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_product_category', $this->customer_product_category])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customerProductBaseProduct.product_name', $this->customerProductBaseProduct]);
```

The column does nothing when I try to filter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump` the variable `$this->customerProductBaseProduct` when you put something in the filter of that column?

Comment: returns a null value

Comment: That is because `$this->load($params);` is not loading the parameter value you are searching with to the model. How does your query url look like?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get it working; see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I filter relational column

```
class UserSearch extends User
{
    public $company_name;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'company_name'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    public function search()
    {
        $query = User::find();
        $query->joinWith(['client c']); //set relation alias

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'first_name', $this->first_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'last_name', $this->last_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', "c.company_name", $this->company_name]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

and use `company_name` attribute in your column definition.

Comment: What is c.company_name in ->andFilterWhere(['like', "c.company_name", $this->company_name])? Your join is on a table client c

Comment: `c` is an alias for `client` table I've set on `$query->joinWith(['client c']);`. it's on the document [\yii\db\ActiveQuery::joinWith](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveQuery.php#L388)

Comment: Do you need the alias? Could you have used client.company_name instead?

Comment: are you sure? take a look at this query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users LEFT JOIN clients ON users.client_id = clients.id WHERE (client.company_name LIKE '%vir%')`, it's from `$query->joinWith(['client'])` without an alias, and gonna through `Unknown column 'client.company_name' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Hmmmm. Not sure way but using the alias worked. Thanks.

Comment: if you're not using alias than in the query I gave about yii won't set the alias for the table and you're using `client.company_name` which sql couldn't find this column, so you have to use alias or the table name `clients.company_name` (with s)

Comment: this is the query with alias `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users LEFT JOIN clients c ON users.client_id = c.id WHERE c.company_name LIKE '%s%')`